# Ifstream infinite loop (it never seems to find the marker to stop reading)

Tags: c++, loops, infinite-loop, ifstream, peek

A rather quick question... I can't figure out why this loop never ends...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 //[city1][city2][distance]

 ifstream sourcefile;

 int data[50][50];



 sourcefile.open("a5.txt");
 if(!sourcefile)
 {
  cout << "file not found" << endl;
  return 1;
 }

 int temp1, temp2, temp3, check;

 char reader;

 check = 0;



 while(reader != 'Q')
 {
  sourcefile >> temp1;
  sourcefile >> temp2;
  sourcefile >> temp3;

  data[temp1][temp2] = temp3;

  cout << "data[" << temp1 << "][" << temp2 << "] = " << temp3 << endl;
  check++;

  if(check > 100)
  {
   cout << "overflow" << endl;
   return 1;
  }

  reader = sourcefile.peek();


 }



 return 0;
}
```

The input file

```
1 2 10
1 4 30
1 5 99    
2 3 50    
2 1 70    
3 5 10    
3 1 50    
4 3 20    
4 5 60    
5 2 40   
Q
```

The output:

```
data[1][2] = 10
data[1][4] = 30
data[1][5] = 99
data[2][3] = 50
data[2][1] = 70
data[3][5] = 10
data[3][1] = 50
data[4][3] = 20
data[4][5] = 60
data[5][2] = 40
data[0][2] = 40
data[0][2] = 40

...
... (repeats "data[0][2] = 40" about 60 more times)
overflow
```

Is this a case of peek getting a failbit character?

Comment: add `sourcefile >> ws;` before the peek. (#include <iomanip>)

Comment: actually, I must have forgot to hit save, your suggestion worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

peek lets you see the next character, which I think in this case is the newline after the distance value.  since it's not Q, the loop tries to read another three integer values, fails, and sets the error bit.  peek, when there's a failure, returns EOF - so you never get to see the Q.

Comment: ah... I thought that might be the problem. I wasn't sure if peek skips whitespace or not

Answer (score 0):

Try the following before starting to read from the file.

```
sourcefile >> std::skipws;
```

It will cause whitespace such as line break to be ignored.

Comment: that had no effect, it still repeated endlessly